# groovy script spaces in string

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

Jenkins groovy fails to take data with spaces while calling the script

```
temp=[]
command = 'sh /tmp/params/template.sh [BOS1 - DMZ]'.execute().text
 command.eachLine{ temp.push(it) }
 return temp
```

Result: [executing templates for [BOS1]
I need to get entire "BOS1 - DMZ" passing as a string but it is failing due to spaces in the string

Comment: Check this and see if it works: `command = ['sh', '/tmp/params/template.sh', 'BOS1 - DMZ'].execute().text`

Comment: no luck,, tried but not reading any data..


String x = "Hello world"

if(x.equals("Hello world")){
   temp=[]
  command = ['cat', '/tmp/vmw_params', 'Hello world'].execute().text
   command.eachLine{ temp.push(it) }
   return temp
}